# Getting crash logs, debug information from android users?

Tags: android, crash-reports

This is my first android app.

The code that is heavily tied to hardware features such as the sample rate of the on-board sensors. On most devices the app works, on some I can catch the error and display a message saying that the device is not compatible, but on some devices (perhaps the fault of the phone manufacturer or faulty drivers), the device simply crashes. I need to know where the crash happens and for what devices.

Does a service exist that will enable me to collect debug information and crash logs from an android app I release on the marketplace. For example, something that will send statistics every time a user's app crashes an interface similar Windows Error reporting appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into https://www.crittercism.com, we use it, and it works nicely.

There's also an open source project for this: http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 1):

Use Acra.
it sends you detailed log right to your google docs

http://code.google.com/p/acra/